# Trouble with getting a function to calculate and loop correctly in C

Tags: c, for-loop, floating-point, printf, function-definition

I am needing to make a program to take user input of iterations to the formula : PI=4(1/1 -(1/3)+(1/5) ... repeating a number of times. MY problems so far is that it is not taking my input accurately.

Bascially my approach was to try and seperate the numerator and denominator wth x in the denominator and try and get it to add 2 but I haven't  even figured out the - + rotation yet since I wanted to make sure what I had was working first.

My first problem was that it was getting random numbers but then I changed the variable type to float and that solved that problem but now everything is straight 0.

```
int pi_formula(float numerator,int x,int n)
{

    numerator=1.0;
    x=1;
    float fraction= numerator/x;
    float total;
    
    printf("%lf",&fraction);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) // loop goes for amount of user input times
        
 
        do
    {
        
        fraction; 
        return(total);
        x+= 2;              
     } while (1);
     
      printf("Estimated PI is : %f",&total);



}
```

When I run this code and the  line

```
printf("%lf",&fraction);
```

will return 0.000000.

I can't tell if I even have the loop written properly because I can't seem to get my input to be rcognized.

Here are the prototypes and the main for reference.

```
int pi_formula(float numerator,int x,int n);


int main ()
{

// Problem 2
    float numerator;
    int x;
    int n;
    printf("ESTIMATE PI\n");
    printf("Enter number of iterations:");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    pi_formula(numerator,x,n);

     




system("pause");
}
```

I had tried setting up printf calls to check the inputs expecting to see what I input but that also comes up 0.

Comment: `printf("%lf",&fraction);` --> `printf("%f", fraction);`

Comment: The `do/while` loop returns on the 1st iteration. The whole thing is odd. `fraction;` does nothing and without the `return(total);` it would loop forever.

Comment: Note that `return(total);` will exit the function immediately, ignoring the nested `for` and `do` loops.

Comment: Also the `int` function returns a `float` value. Please check out compiler warnings. Anyway, never use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C.

Comment: ...and again `printf("Estimated PI is : %f",&total);` --> `printf("Estimated PI is : %f", total);`. There are many mistakes in the code, another is passing an uninitialised argument `numerator` and then overwriting it in the function.

Comment: The only error it shows me is in regard to system pause but I will keep that in mind! 
I must of missed the memo about return statements. How would I then take the previous line continue to apply it to the loop? All while being able to use that in the next function?

Comment: Thank you babe for your input. It helped to clean up my code. Using all your info I can clean up my first problem that I'm also having problems with and hope to get that one going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this function declaration

```
int pi_formula(float numerator,int x,int n)
```

does not make sense at least because it has the return type `int` instead of a floating type and a redundant number of parameters.

The function should be declared at least like

```
double pi_formula( unsigned int n );
```

And your function returns nothing though its return type is not `void` except this while loop

```
    do
{
    
    fraction; 
    return(total);
    x+= 2;              
 } while (1);
```

where `total` has the type `float` that also does not make sense.

There are other mistakes. For example in this call of `printf`

```
printf("Estimated PI is : %f",&total);
```

you are trying to output a pointer as a floating point number.

The function can be defined the following way

```
 double pi_formula( unsigned int n )
 {
     double pi = 0.0;

     for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
     {
         if ( i % 2 == 0 )
         {
             pi += 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 );
         }
         else
         {
             pi -= 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 );
         }  
     }

     return 4 * pi;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
int main( void )
{
    puts( "ESTIMATE PI" );

    printf( "Enter number of iterations: " );
  
    unsigned int n = 0;

    if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) == 1 )
    {
         printf( "Estimated PI is : %f\n", pi_formula( n ) );
    }
}
```

Here is all the code combined together

```
#include <stdio.h>

double pi_formula( unsigned int n )
{
    double pi = 0.0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            pi += 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            pi -= 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 );
        }
    }

    return 4 * pi;
}

int main( void )
{
    puts( "ESTIMATE PI" );

    printf( "Enter number of iterations: " );

    unsigned int n = 0;

    if (scanf( "%u", &n ) == 1)
    {
        printf( "Estimated PI is : %f\n", pi_formula( n ) );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
ESTIMATE PI
Enter number of iterations: 9999
Estimated PI is : 3.141693
```

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. I have not paid attention to the expressions.:)

Comment: I thought you had to list all the variables in the prototype that would be used in the function later on? Hence why I have the 3 listed there. We also haven't learned about "unsigned int " yet is that the same as listing it as int n; with no equals sign?

Comment: @Spongebuild All other variables are auxiliary local variables of the function. The function needs only the number of iterations. unsigned int is the type for non-negative integer values. There is no sense to pass a negative number to the function.

Comment: I am now getting a negative output after making some of the changes so getting closer. user input of 9999 should be getting at least 3. something and I got  -0.858507

Comment: @Spongebuild It seems you copied the code with your own typos. I can not reproduce your output. See my appended answer.

Comment: @Spongebuild Maybe you wrote pi = 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 ); instead of pi -= 1.0 / ( 2 * i + 1 );.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me here, what is this puts you have there? We have not covered that so I can't use that code. Though I did change my for statement from i=1 and i<=n to match yours.  And that solved me problem! I think my understanding was that I wanted it to start on iteration 1? So I'm little lost how 0 solves that problem. Though I fixed so much based on your help so thank you.

Comment: @Spongebuild We, beginners, should help each other. :) In C  indecies start from 0. A range [1, n] is equivalent to the range [0, n).